# Is there a Tool Tip for CodenameOne?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a button property that is analogous to swing's tool tip? I want the user to be able to long press a button and see a message describing the button, but I can't find any such property. (The button doesn't and can't have a visible name.) Tool tips are so useful to users, so I assumed there must be one, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The ToastBar (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/toastbar-gaussian-blur.html) might work.

There was also an old demo using the GlassPane for a tutorial overlay which allowed some quite neat effects. Can't find it on the CN1 website now though.

Comment: You are referring to this post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/walk-thru-tutorial.html I would also suggest using the `InteractionDialog` possibly as a popup to show this which is what we do in the validation error messages. Tooltips don't really exist as a concept in touch UI's but I'm thinking about adding "real" tooltip support for the desktop/JavaScript port which will be useful for our new preferences UI.

Comment: Tool tips do seem to exist on my Android. And the ToastBar may be useful ways to implement one, but that doesn't help me with the long press. I don't see a long-press event type for buttons, although I see one for keystrokes. My Android uses long-press for a lot of things. For example, the downloads window, which is currently filled with installers for the app I'm building, lets me open an installer with a normal touch, but lets me select an installer without opening it with a long press. Is there a way to detect this kind of event?

Comment: Here's an example of a tool tip in Android. In the standard "Contacts" app, do a long-press on the search button. A tool tip will appear with the word "Search."